# What does it mean by "the apparent linewidth is limited by the measurement resolution, which is $7.5 \ \text{GHz} \ (0.25 \ \text{cm$^{-1}$})$"?

Tags: laser, photonics

The datasheet for [this](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=L795VH1) VCSEL has the following graph:

> [image]

What does it mean by "the apparent linewidth is limited by the measurement resolution, which is $7.5 \ \text{GHz} \ (0.25 \ \text{cm$^{-1}$})$"? I am actually interested in this laser's narrow spectral linewidth, so it seems to me that this is saying that the spectral linewidth is *even better* than what it looks like on the graph, but that they could not show it, because it reached the limit of their measuring devices?

Comment: Basically you are correct.

Comment: In this case if you give it some thought and feel confident that you've got it right (I do as well) then it's fine to post an answer to your own question. If there's no arguments to the contrary then a few days later I it would also be fine to just go ahead and accept your own answer. I wish we had a separate *Optics SE site!*